# How to use Resource bundle(Client Bundle) in JSNI?

Tags: css, gwt, resourcebundle, jsni

I am trying to use client bundle of css resource in JSNI but couldn't find any helpful code.
I want to know how to call css resource in JSNI and how exaclty to use client bundle in JSNI.

My Normal code:--

```
 Resource.INSTANCE.button().ensureInjected();

 Resource res = GWT.create(Resource.class);

 button.setStyleName(res.button().gwtbutton());
```

How to write in jsni?

Here Resource----> is interface extend clientbundle.
gwtbutton ---> is css.

I have read in this link https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-web-toolkit/94v4tjCZiBo that we can use the CssResource through jsni. But I'm unclear about his usage its syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no magic here (OK, there is a bit, but behind the scenes). Your `Resource` interface's implementation is automatically generated by GWT, so when you call `res.button().gwtbutton()`, it will return a proper name for the style you are referencing from a CSS file. This name could be obfuscated, with a prefix, etc. It doesn't matter to you - in the end it's just a string, a style's name. Just pass it as a `String` to your JSNI method:

```
public native void addStyle(String style) /*-{
    // Add style to a DOM element
}-*/;

// Invoke like so:
addStyle(res.button().gwtbutton());
```

If you want to use your ClientBundle directly in JSNI code:

```
// First, get Resource instance from a static field
var resource = @package.Resource::INSTANCE;
// Then, get the CssResource with the style
var button = resource.@package.Resource::button()();
// Finally, get the style's name
var gwtButton = button.@package.Button::gwtButton()();
```

Substitute `package.Resource` for the proper qualified name (package + class name) of the `Resource` interface. Use the code completion offered by Google Plugin for Eclipse if needed. Do the same for the type returned by the `button` method (it's probably some interface extending `CssResource`).

If you are troubled by the syntax, please [dig through the documentation](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSNI.html#methods-fields) or look into some tutorials on Java Native Interface - it shares a lot of similarities with JSNI and might be better documented.

Comment: Sir, I want to use my css directly in jsni. I just want help in syntax.

Comment: There's a link there to the official documentation on JSNI and how to invoke Java code from it, not to mention examples in the thread you linked. What part is giving you trouble? If you are using Eclipse and the Google Plugin for Ecplise, there should be [code completion available in JSNI methods to help you build the invocation](https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/gwt_jsni).

Comment: Its all syntax error i am getting. I have tried this much.

Comment: var lib = @com.ruchi.bundle.client.Resource::INSTANCE;
 var style = lib.@com.xyz.bundle.client.Resource::button().gwtbutton();                but through this still i am unable in adding css (gwtbutton)

Comment: Could you post the exception?

Comment: java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast com.ruchi.bundle.client.Resource_default_InlineClientBundleGenerator$1 to com.ruchi.bundle.client.Button

Comment: hey sorry its my mistake i.e. class cast exception occur, but now its resolved. Thanks
can you answer this question on http://www.enggheads.com/#!question/1421080044931

Comment: Sorry, but no - it seems like you are asking a question before giving it some thought yourself. You should have been able to figure out the answer to the question on enggheads (why not stackoverflow?). If not, you need to learn some Javascript. Please do your own research, learning, etc. before asking such questions - show what you've done, what worked, what not. So far, it looks like you are just asking us to do your job.